# How to call outer class function from inner class

Tags: python, class

I've got three files in my project:
**main.py**, **slider.py**, **ui.py**. So **main.py** imports **ui.py**, which imports **slider.py**.

There are three classes: **App** in main.py, **Slider** in slider.py, **Ui_MainWindow** in ui.py

App inherits Ui_MainWindow, Ui_MainWindow sets its attribute as Slider Class.
Basically I'm making new attribute for App Class that is Slider Class from slider.py. How do I access its(App) attributes from inner class(Slider)?

```
#main.py
from ui import Ui_MainWindow
class App(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        super().__init__()

#ui.py
from slider import Slider
class Ui_MainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = Slider()

#slider.py
class Slider():
    def __init__(self):
        # name 'App' is not defined
        print(App.x)
```

Comment: I also can't edit ui.py, cause it is generated from scratch every time I run main.py

Comment: You will need to import main.py in your slider.py

Comment: @TobiasWilfert, thanks a lot. I've got one more question. How do I call App's method in Slider Class?
I call App.do() method, which meant to change App.canvas.pen attribute. So I call App.do(self, val) in Slider. do() is basically: self.canvas.pen = val.
But when I send self attribute it means I send Slider in do()
If I send App instead of self in App.do(self, val), it says App has no attribute canvas(in do() function)

Comment: Change `def __init__(self):` to `def __init__(self, app):`, then `app.do(...`